# What might cause System.Net Error:AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient, tls1.2

I have a simple piece of https connection code that works well with one ssl host, connecting even though the root certificate authority is untrusted (this is a sandbox environment, so we're not worried about the security hole this creates, for now), and loading the certificate and key from text files, using the Nuget package `OpenSSL.X509Certificate2Provider`:

```
    public async Task<string> Register()
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            var rawcert = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\OpenSSL\bin\certTransport.pem");
            var rawkey = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\OpenSSL\bin\privateKeyTransport.key");

            var provider = new CertificateFromFileProvider(rawcert, rawkey);
            var cert = provider.Certificate;
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                (HttpRequestMessage req, X509Certificate2 cert2, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors err) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };

            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://{uri}/");
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync("register");
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I point this code to another host, that should be secured in precisely the same manner, I get the following error:
`System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

And digging into the logs, I discover:
`System.Net Information: 0 : [35036] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Error: 0 : [35036] AcquireCredentialsHandle() failed with error 0X8009030D.`

Searching stack for this, I find many errors related to certificate store permissions, but the client certificate in this case isn't loaded from the store.

I also find many issues relating to SecurityProtocolType. I have verified that the server is using Tls1.2 (only).

I'm calling the code from a unit test within VS 2017 Enterprise running with Administrative privileges on Win10 x64. The code is contained in a .Net 4.7 Class Library, not hosted in IIS.

What could be causing this issue?

**UPDATE**
Following @Jeroen Mostert's useful comments below, I tried a basic connection test with OpenSSL. Slightly anonymised results:

```
OpenSSL> s_client -connect {REMOVED}:443 -CAfile C:\OpenSSL\bin\archive-ii\transport-production-new\certTransport.pem
CONNECTED(000001F0)
depth=2 C = GB, O = OK, CN = {REMOVED} Root CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/OU={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED}
i:/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Issuing CA
1 s:/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Issuing CA
i:/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Root CA
2 s:/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Root CA
i:/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{REMOVED}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/OU={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED}
issuer=/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Issuing CA
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Issuing CA
/C=GB/O={REMOVED}/CN={REMOVED} Root CA
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms:     RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5155 bytes and written 446 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: {REMOVED}
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1527164830
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
```

Is there anything amiss there?

I've also looked in the CAPI2 log (as suggested in the comments). This shows errors relating to the root certificate not being trusted, like this:
[image]

Does this mean my validation callbacks aren't working - and if so, any idea why that would be?

**Further Update:**

If I remove the line of code which attaches the certificate, then the error goes away - I get through to the MTLS test endpoint (but, of course, fail the MTLS test that is conducted there).

What does this suggest? A problem with the certificate itself?

Comment: FWIW, 0x8009030D is `SEC_E_UNKNOWN_CREDENTIALS`, "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized", as returned by [`AcquireCredentialsHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa374716). This should happen before actual certificate validation occurs (I *think*); it basically means the function didn't like what was in [`SCHANNEL_CRED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa379810), which could be a discrepancy in what .NET provides versus what Schannel is configured to support on that server. Not that that makes finding the root cause much easier.

Comment: I see OpenSSL there -- you could consider using `openssl s_client` to verify the basics, that your certificate works with the server (and also exactly what happens during the handshakes, to see if there are obvious differences between host X and Y that would explain why .NET might fail).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - see update above.

Comment: Is the connection test for the working host or the failing host? Ideally you'd compare both.

Comment: That's the failing host. I'll have a look to see if anything is different on the working host.

Comment: You may be able to use the CAPI2 log. If you enable this all TLS/SSL handshake done in Windows is logged. It is a bit complicated to explain how to do that but I found a blog post with some information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saurabs/2016/10/27/ssltls-introduction-to-capi2-traces/

Comment: Thanks @MartinLiversage - that did throw up a few errors. See update above.

Comment: The certificate chain error may not be the smoking gun, because it could be handled later by the stack (the fact that it is not the error presented at the top level is suspect). Again, comparing it with the working case would be very insightful -- if that also shows this error, you know it's not the problem. If it doesn't, then it is.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately they've taken down that test endpoint and replaced it with another, with which we now have the same problem, so I don't have a working one to compare with. I'm wondering if this could be an issue with the actual certificates, but otherwise I'm just going around in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here in the end was with the output of the `CertificateFromFileProvider` method of the `OpenSSL.X509Certificate2Provider` NuGet package.

For whatever reason, the certificate created would not work correctly. Taking the same input files and generating a `.pfx` with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) resulted in an `X509Certificate2` that worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone comes across this, and the first answer does not solve your problem:

As Jeroen Mostert pointed out, the error `0x8009030D` is `SEC_E_UNKNOWN_CREDENTIALS`, resolves to *The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized* and is thrown by the [AcquireCredentialsHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-acquirecredentialshandlew) function.

In my case the problem was that the user account running the program had insufficient rights (no read rights) on the certificate, and could not retrieve the private key from the certificate. Solution was to open the certificate store that stored the certificate, right click on it, then click on "All Tasks" -> "Manage Private Keys..." to open the Permissions window:

[image]

Inside that window give the account that is running the program READ rights to access the certificate (in my case it was the NETWORK SERVICE account for a windows service):

[image]